# Realize a frame for a simplified Stream API but use Builder

Tags: java, builder

There is a task in which need to finished the class. I don't quite understand how can use the Builder pattern here?( If these were fields of a class, well, understand, but with methods it doesn’t work, I don’t understand( Guys with experience can you help me pls)
There are some conditions:

1. Realize a frame for a simplified Stream API.
2. BestStream works only with the Integer type.
3. And need to use pattern Builder.

- Method *of* - initial data.
- Method *map* - converts a number to another number(element * 2).
- Method *filter* - filters the stream of elements(element == 2).
- Method *collect* - collects all elements from the source according to the specified map and filter conditions.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
    
public class BestStream {
    public static BestStream of(List<Integer> source) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    
    public BestStream map(Function<Integer, Integer> fun) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    
    public BestStream filter(Predicate<Integer> fun) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    
    public List<Integer> collect() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think fields in your case are the "functional functions" (Function and Predicate), as you can notice they're passed as parameter to your method.

Under this view you can apply a builder where you can "build" a stream which operates in this order:

1. maps the number by the map field
2. filter them by the filter field
3. build collection as result

An example:

```
private static class BestStream {
    private final Stream<Integer> source;
    private Function<Integer, Integer> map;
    private Predicate<Integer> filter;

    private BestStream(Stream<Integer> source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public static BestStream of(List<Integer> source) {
        return new BestStream(source.stream());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Integer> collect =
                BestStream.of(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 9))
                        .filter(i -> Objects.equals(i, 2))
                        .map(i -> i * 2)
                        .collect();
    }

    public BestStream map(Function<Integer, Integer> fun) {
        this.map = fun;
        return this;
    }

    public BestStream filter(Predicate<Integer> fun) {
        this.filter = fun;
        return this;
    }

    public List<Integer> collect() {
        return source.map(map).filter(filter).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: After your solution, I figured out how it works! Thank You too)

Comment: If you find the answer correct and useful, could you please set it as accepted?

Comment: If don't use Stream API methods in last method collect, but create own one?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to solve this is to break it down into multiple classes.

First, the interface users of your API see:

```java
package example;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;
import java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator;

public interface BestStream {

    static BestStream of(List<Integer> list) {
        return new BestStreamListSource(list);
    }

    BestStream filter(IntPredicate predicate);
    BestStream map(IntUnaryOperator operator);
    List<Integer> collect();
}
```

secondly an interface for internal purposes:

```java
package example;

public interface BestStreamSource extends BestStream {

    Integer next();
}
```

Now a base implementation of your internal `BestStreamSource` interface which is later used by the actual implementations:

```java
package example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;
import java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator;

public abstract class BaseBestStreamSource implements BestStreamSource {

    @Override
    public BestStream filter(IntPredicate predicate) {
        return new BestStreamFilteredSource(this, predicate);
    }

    @Override
    public BestStream map(IntUnaryOperator operator) {
        return new BestStreamMappingSource(this, operator);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> collect() {
        final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer value = null;

        while ((value = next()) != null) {
            result.add(value);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now you have 3 classes that actually do the work:

- One source, reading the elements from the list
- One that does filtering, based on any Source
- One that does mapping, based on any Source

```java
package example;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class BestStreamListSource extends BaseBestStreamSource {

    private final List<Integer> list;
    private int index;

    public BestStreamListSource(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = Objects.requireNonNull(list);
        this.index = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        if (this.index < this.list.size()) {
            return this.list.get(this.index++);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
package example;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;

public class BestStreamFilteredSource extends BaseBestStreamSource {

    private final BestStreamSource parent;
    private final IntPredicate predicate;

    public BestStreamFilteredSource(BestStreamSource parent, IntPredicate predicate) {
        this.parent = Objects.requireNonNull(parent);
        this.predicate = Objects.requireNonNull(predicate);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        final int[] holder = new int[1];
        Integer value = null;
        boolean foundMatch = false;

        while (!foundMatch && (value = this.parent.next()) != null) {
            foundMatch = this.predicate.test(value);
        }

        if (foundMatch) {
            return value;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
package example;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator;

public class BestStreamMappingSource extends BaseBestStreamSource {

    private final BestStreamSource parent;
    private final IntUnaryOperator mapping;

    public BestStreamMappingSource(BestStreamSource parent, IntUnaryOperator mapping) {
        this.parent = Objects.requireNonNull(parent);
        this.mapping = Objects.requireNonNull(mapping);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        Integer value = this.parent.next();
        if (value != null) {
            value = this.mapping.applyAsInt(value);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

With that, you can chain whatever filter and mapping you want to do

Comment: Thanks for decision, but is too difficult for me yet )